# How to trigger an action on double-tap of a keyboard button?

Tags: linux, debian, xmonad

I'd like to learn how to trigger something in my debian box on double-tap of a key (let's say l-shift). My setup is X11 based. Should I look into doing in my MW (xmonad) or on a lower level? 
Forgive my ignorance, but I'm used to windows and the wonderful autohotkey.
Why? To remap ctrl to capslock, and have capslock on double-tap of l-shift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action of double-tapping would ideally be program-independent and should thus be implemented at a lower level than user programs or even window managers (which you don't want grabbing all keypresses to check for double-tapping).

The correct place to implement a feature like this would be in the [X keyboard extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XKB). It could detect double tapping and let the user configure the keyname associated with it. Unfortunately, XKB does not yet support the action of double-tapping. You can do other cool things though, like remapping keys with xmodmap or even writing novel keyboard layouts (have look at the files in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols`)

Comment: "Unfortunately, XKB does not yet support the action of double-tapping."  -- is this still the case in 2022?

Comment: The XKB specification hasn't changed since 1996, and [their wiki](https://www.x.org/wiki/XKB/) hasn't been updated since 2013. I think it's safe to conclude that this feature will never be added.

Answer (score 0):

Even if not possible as of today, it seems a service like that implemented by [evremap](https://github.com/wez/evremap#why) could be extended to support detecting and mapping double-taps in a custom way.
If someone is very interested, it might be implemented there or in a fork.
See the GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/wez/evremap/issues/18).