# On Windows, is there a way to map double-tapping the Shift key to make it behave as Capslock, like keyboards on mobile?

Tags: keyboard, remapping, capslock, shift

I've recently remapped the Capslock key to Esc and it's great, but I also miss its actual functionality at times. So I wondered if it would be possible to make the Shift key behave as it does for keyboards on iOS, Android etc, where you just tap it twice and it behaves as the Capslock key until you double-tap it again.

I looked around on the internet and found nothing, looked around here and found [this similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/533670/how-to-trigger-an-action-on-double-tap-of-a-keyboard-button), which addresses how to do it on Linux, and [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/888574/how-to-remap-double-shift-keystroke-to-capslock-key), which asks for the same procedure on Windows, but went unanswered. So here I am giving it another go.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use AutoIT to add a hotkey. Now, you could do double-shift, but I would recommend a combination of keys instead. Capturing a key like shift with a hotkey program will cause plenty of other problems.

Tools for doing so:

1. [HotKeySet function in AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/HotKeySet.htm)
2. [Keybinding Forum Post](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/132100-hotkeyset-using-more-than-one-key-bind/)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the help, that's a good point about capturing the shift key. I'm going to try out your suggestion and if it works I'll accept the answer. Thanks again.

Comment: AutoIt has a bunch of useful things that I use all the time. Another one is VoiceAttack. Its primarily billed as for games, but I use it to add granular voice control to my Systems Administration.

Comment: I ended up not using AutoIT but you sent me on a path where I ended up stumbling onto AutoHotKey, which, along with your suggestion for choosing a combination of keys instead of a double-tap, helped me solve the problem. So I accepted your answer, thanks a lot. For anyone wondering, I'll post what I did below.

Comment: Ya, AutoHotKey is nice as well. Auto it has the same capabilities but does require more scripting and AutoHotkey does make it super easy.

Answer (score 1):

So I thought Matthew Williams had a pretty good point about going with a combination of keys instead of a double-tap, and it turns out AutoHotKey makes doing this ridiculously trivial. I just created a `.ahk` file with the following content:

```
+Capslock::Capslock
Capslock::Esc
```

That's the file in its entirety and it solves the problem perfectly. The first line is a shortcut for a `Shift + Capslock` combination, and it means that, when I press it, it makes `Capslock` behave as a normal `Capslock` key, but when I just tap it once, it behaves like the `Esc` key, also as intended.

I had originally remapped the `Capslock` key to `Esc` with SharpKeys, but this is an infinitely simpler and better solution.